# Custom Paint Path On Stack On Parent

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter, my issue comes with custom paint on nested stack, when keyboard showing, custom paint are resizing, its happen on android and ios.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.centerLeft,
          colors: [gPurple, gPurple, gBlue],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120, bottom: 160, left: 20, right: 20),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomPaint(
            size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 400),
            painter: CurvedPainterTop(),
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 800),
            painter: CurvedPainterBottom(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          Text(
            "Login",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: txtHmAmount,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 140, left: 40, right: 40),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text("Email", style: txtHmTMenuB),
          Row(children: const [
            Icon(Icons.mail_outline, color: Colors.grey, size: 25),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Expanded(child: TextField())
          ]),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          const Text("Password", style: txtHmTMenuB),
          Row(children: const [
            Icon(Icons.lock_outline, color: Colors.grey, size: 25),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Expanded(child: TextField())
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

> before keyboard show

[image]

> after keyboard show
> [image]

> on iOS Simulator
> [image]

any suggest what should do to keep stack still as 1st picture?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to false for your Scaffold